# File upload to multiple Opportunity

Tags: apex

I have requirement to upload a common file to more than 400 opportunities. I am executing below script on Anonymous window but getting error as **Variable does not exist: Id**

```
ContentDocumentLink objCDL = new ContentDocumentLink();
List<Opportunity> opp = [select Id from Opportunity where Name Like '%SVO Test%'];
for(Opportunity o : opp)
{
    objCDL.ContentDocumentId = '0695A000004dRpRQAU';//Id of the file
    objCDL.LinkedEntityId = opp.Id; //Id of the record for sharing
    objCDL.ShareType = 'V';
    insert objCDL;
}
insert objCDL;
```

Comment: Hi Rohit Kumar, While assigning the opportunity id you are not using the correct variable. Can you try with this code.`objCDL.LinkedEntityId =o.Id;`

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestion:

1. Prepare list of ContentDocument instead of a single record.
2. Insert outside the loop not in the for loop.

   ```
    List<ContentDocumentLink> objCDLs = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

    List<Opportunity> opp = [select Id from Opportunity where Name Like '%SVO Test%' LIMIT 2000];

    for(Opportunity o : opp)
    {
    ContentDocumentLink objCDL = new ContentDocumentLink ();
    objCDL.ContentDocumentId = '0695A000004dRpRQAU';//Id of the file
    objCDL.LinkedEntityId = opp.Id; //Id of the record for sharing
    objCDL.ShareType = 'V';
    objCDLs.add(objCDL_;
    }

    insert objCDLs;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ContentDocumentLink objCDL = new ContentDocumentLink();
List<Opportunity> opp = [select Id from Opportunity where Name Like '%SVO Test%'];
for(Opportunity o : opp)
{
objCDL.ContentDocumentId = '0695A000004dRpRQAU';//Id of the file
objCDL.LinkedEntityId = o.Id; //Id of the record for sharing
objCDL.ShareType = 'V';
insert objCDL;
}
insert objCDL;
```

The returned error resides in using "opp.Id" instead of the single variable from your loop "o.Id".
objCDL.LinkedEntityId = **o.Id**;